# Havoc while escaping quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes

I am trying to build a custom HTML/Javascript command using the following Javascript (for now, "dialogText" contains the name of a vegetable, but it may later contain HTML tags too):

```
str = str + "<span onClick=showDialog('"+dialogText+"')>";
```

When dialogText is only one word long (i.e. "Basil"), this works correctly, giving the following result:

```
<span onclick="showDialog('Basil')">
```

But when dialogText includes more than one word (i.e. "Beet root"), this fails. The result is syntactically invalid and generates a Javascript error:

```
<span onclick="showDialog('Beet" root')="">
```

Why does this happen (where did the equals sign come from?)?

And how can I change the code so that it works?

Comment: Avoid using inline event handlers and you won't have to escape quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't looking at the HTML you are generating, you are converting that HTML to a DOM and then serializing it back to HTML.

Since you have a `"` as data in the attribute value, but haven't represented it as a character reference (`&quot;`), and the value is limited with `"` - the `"` ends the attribute.

You then start a new attribute.

Since the next attribute doesn't have a value, it gets assigned an empty string when the browser attempts to error correct.

---

In general, avoid mashing strings together to generate HTML for conversion to a DOM. Use DOM methods directly instead.

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    showDialog(dialogText);
});
```